# Symfony2 - EventListener changing data onFlush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

I am trying to generate a Pdf with  KnpSnappyBundle and save the position in doctrine when my Bill Entity is generated.

I need the tamplating service for that, which i can't get inside an Entity.

I read into EventListener and tried to get one to work.

My config.yml

```
services:
    bill.listener:
        class: MyCompany\CompanyBundle\EventListener\BillListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }
```

And my Listener

```
namespace MyCompany\CompanyBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;

class BillListener
{
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $insertions) {
            foreach ($insertions as $entity) {
                if ($entity instanceof Bill) {
                    $entity->setFilename("test.pdf");

                    $md = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
                    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($md, $entity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Bill Entity has a setFilename function where I want to save the position of the generated Bill. But i can't get even that to work.

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot the namespace of the Bill class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop messing with the UOW (it's kind of hacking), just flush it again:

**Config**

```
services:
    bill.listener:
        class: MyCompany\CompanyBundle\EventListener\BillListener
        arguments: ["@pdf_service"]
        tags :
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

**Listener**

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\CompanyBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;

use MyCompany\CompanyBundle\Service\MyPDFService;
use MyCompany\CompanyBundle\Entity\Bill;

class BillListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    protected $pdfs;
    protected $bills;

    public function __construct(MyPDFService $pdfs)
    {
        $this->pdfs = $pdfs;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'onFlush',
            'postFlush'
        ];
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $event)
    {
        $this->bills = [];
        /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
        $em = $event->getEntityManager();
        /* @var $uow \Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork */
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {

            if ($entity instanceof Bill) {

                $this->bills[] = $entity;
            }
        }
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $event)
    {
        if (!empty($this->bills)) {

            /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
            $em = $event->getEntityManager();

            foreach ($this->bills as $bill) {

                /* @var $bill \MyCompany\CompanyBundle\Entity\Bill */
                $this->pdfs->generateFor($bill);
                $em->persist($bill);
            }

            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked for me. had to change the getSubscribedEvents function to
    return array(
        'onFlush',
        'postFlush'
    );

Comment: Sorry but... "insertion" only happens once, the first time an entity is persisted. Anyway, the loop can be avoided using some property as a flag.

Comment: Does not this solution break the ATOMIC-ity of the operation? What if the second flush fail? Ok, in this case, the PDFs will not be generated, but what if the second flush should be a really important thing? This can cause inconsistency no?

Comment: Well, then you should take care of it, maybe in that case what you really need is a service to manage your operation the way you want, just in one transaction.

Comment: You should remove this listener once it has been triggered by Doctrine, so you avoid a potential infinite loop. (something like $em->getEventManager()->removeEventListener(.....)

Comment: Seems like calling flush() in postFlush is not a good idea "EntityManager#flush() can NOT be called safely inside ": http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postflush